# Search for Value in all Columns in SQL Table

Tags: sql, search

i want to search for a value in all columns in a SQL table.
I have different data types, like a bigInt, booleans or strings.
My question now is, how is it possible to search a value in all columns in a SQL Table?

Thanks for your help.

Kind regards
Max

Comment: Write a query with each conversion of your input for each column type? `WHERE col1 = TO_CHAR/ CAST INTO VARCHAR.... (input) OR col2 = TO_NUMBER/ CAST INTO NUM/INT... (input) OR col3 = TO_DATE/...... OR col4 = ... OR col5 = ....`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no shortcut for this, you have to specify the list of columns you wish to search.

```
SELECT * 
FROM table_name 
WHERE column1 LIKE '%search_key%' OR 
      column2 LIKE '%search_key%' OR  
      column3 LIKE '%search_key%'
```

Or create metadata for all the columns into a single column and use `like` on the metadata column